# mysql - best way to avoid duplicates

Tags: mysql, performance, duplicates

I am very new to the database game so forgive my ignorance.

I am loading millions of rows into a simply structured MySQL database table

```
SQLStr = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'f:/Smallscale/02 MMToTxt/flat.txt'
  INTO TABLE `GMLObjects` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  LINES STARTING BY 'XXX';"
```

At the moment the table has been set to no duplicates against one field.

However, I am wondering if it would be quicker to remove the no duplicates rule and deal with the problem of duplicates later, either by using `ALTER TABLE` or `SELECT DISTINCT`, or some such query.

What are your thoughts?

P.S the database engine is InnoDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not "alter" a table with duplicates into a table without.

MySQL can not know which of the rows it should remove. It would mean a lot of work and trouble to delete them later, and it would produce deleted entries without any benefit.

So avoid duplicates as early as possible.

Comment: You can add a unique key to a table and use `ignore` no drop the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Why load duplicates in your DB in the first place?

Avoid them as early as possible. That is better for performance and you don't have to write complicated queries.